# Call super when overriding overloaded operator in groovy++

Tags: groovy, operator-overloading, groovy++

This is the code I have

```
@Typed class FooMap extends LinkedHashMap {
  def doSomeFoo() {
    // ...
  }

  FooMap plus(Collection coll) {
    super.plus(coll)
  }
}
```

While it works in plain Groovy, compiling it with Groovy++ gives an error: `Cannot reference default groovy method 'plus' using 'super'. Call the static method instead`. I don't if it's a bug in Groovy++, or it's meant to work this way.  Anyway, I want to call `super` in a typed way.  How can I workaround this situation?

The reason why I want such a method is that I want this code to compile.

```
FooMap map = new FooMap() + [bar: 42]
map.doSomeFoo()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly why groovy++ doesn't allow the super method to be called, but the static method it refers to is in `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods`:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods

assert DefaultGroovyMethods.plus([one: 1], [two: 2]) == [one: 1, two: 2]
```

You can get the behaviour you're looking for by calling that.